# deploying a java SE application in Netbeans8

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-8

I have built a GUI application in Java using Netbeans 8.0 and have linked it to a MySQL database on my system using JDBC.
This application provides login functionality to its users and lets them take a survey.
My problem is to host this application on the internet and collect the data filled by users in MySQL database.
Can someone please suggest how to go about this??

I am a newbie and have tried using java web start to make this work.But no success yet.Please suggest how should I go about this.I'm saturated with all the googling.

Comment: check this link https://netbeans.org/features/java-on-server/deployment.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what your problem is. Normally a GUI application is a program which can run on a desktop machine. If I understood well, you want to create something which connects to a remote database. You can do this with your application but you need to distribuite it along the users. If you want to run a java code on host so that people can use it in internet like a webpage  you need one of these:

- applets
- a webserver capable which can run java and jsp/jsf or whatever

If you can be more specific I can help you in a better way.

Cheers